# Opengl es 2.0 3d

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, textures

I am looking for a tutorial about opengl es 2.0 for android,
until now I have been using andEngine for 2d opengl es 1.x,
I am looking forward being able to build an app in 3d from scratch, not using someone's engine.
If its possible, I want the tutorial to explain about 3d textures too, and how to use everything.
Are there any good tutorials for this?

I am new to OpenGl, but not to the android platform. i had a lot of experience with canvas and andEngine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am new to both Android and Open GL ES, and I found [this](http://www.learnopengles.com) extremely helpful. It goes through step-by-step how OpenGL ES works, shapes, colours, blending, vertex buffers, fragment and vertex shaders, texture loading... from a relatively beginner perspective.